# Regex - Discard any word starts with nonDecimal in a string

Tags: python, regex

In this case, I would not like to include first element '223', any suggestion?

```
re.findall(pattern=r"[^\D][-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?", string="        LComb_1_2_223  -4.00000000E+00  500000E+01  -1.09000000E-02  2.00E+00  22  5.23  ")

# out: ['223', '4.00000000E+00', '500000E+01', '1.09000000E-02', '0.00000000E+00']
```

Comment: If you require the `e` part, remove `(?:` and `)?`. Also, note that `[^\D]` = `\d`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made the decimal point optional with `\.?` if you replace it with `\.` you will only get numbers with a decimal point:

```py
import re

text = "        LComb_1_2_223  -4.00000000E+00  500000E+01  -1.09000000E-02  0.00000000E+00"
results = re.findall(pattern=r"[^\D][-+]?[0-9]*\.[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?", string=text)

print(results)  # ['4.00000000E+00', '1.09000000E-02', '0.00000000E+00']
```

edit:
based on you comment i changed the regex to the following that captures a group after any whitespace charachters with two optional groups, the decimal and the exponent

```py
import re
text = "        LComb_1_2_223  -4.00000000E+00  500000E+01  -1.09000000E-02  0.00000000E+00 233"
results = re.findall(pattern=r"\s([-+]?\d+(?:\.[0-9]+)?(?:[eE][-+]?\d+)?)", string=text)
print(results)  # ['-4.00000000E+00', '500000E+01', '-1.09000000E-02', '0.00000000E+00', '233']
```

Comment: Thanks, however it will not pick a hole integer for example '22' in this  `string="        LComb_1_2_223  -4.00000000E+00  500000E+01  -1.09000000E-02  2.00E+00  22  5.23  "`  Intention is just to discard whole word starts with Letter or special character. Updated the original question.